# Interface from another project can not be found

Tags: c#, visual-studio, interface, project

Why i cant use the IInterface at ConsoleApp project? Shouldn't I be able too since it's in the same namespace?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you add the project with the interface as reference to the one using it?

Comment: In general if you want to re-use a class or interface, it's best to put it into a class library and make it have public visibility. Just like @fredrik said, ensure you have a reference to the containing project and also check that the visibility is `public`

Answer (score 0):

Except UnitTest-Projects. It is fine to not use a class library there. But since this is not the case there you are right